# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: ajax, azure, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

Hi I am a beginner in ASP.net. I am trying to send the response through ajax to web API mvc which is hosted in azure I get the following error 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long) I used JSONP

Comment: It would be great if you give more information...